# How to transform:scale the top and bottom part of a div using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

How can I scale just the top and bottom part of a `<div>` using CSS? Because using `transform: scale(1.01);` makes the whole div scale out and I just want the top and bottom part of the image to be expanded.

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: If you want people to help you, consider adding some code to your questions and/or a link to a JSFiddle. That allows us to debug your problem, which makes it a lot easier to figure out why things aren't doing what you expect them to do.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: I think OP has given enough information here. They are trying to scale a `div` using `scale(1.01)` and are seeing it expand on all directions instead of just top and bottom. I personally don't think a demo is required here (unless I have grossly misunderstood the question).

Comment: @Harry : Without looking at the actual use case, I find it difficult to suggest the best approach to his problem. There are possibly better ways to achieve the desired effect that don't involve using a `transform` at all.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: That I agree, there could be different ways to achieve the effect but OP is asking about transforming just the top and bottom for which the statement and screenshot seem clear enough. As you'd see from the image, the expansion is just vertical. Are the other approaches going to better - I can't comment. In my opinion, a transform is better because it is not resource intensive unlike height changes etc, (*Note:* Its just my opinion. You are 100% entitled to yours. I just said what I felt)

Comment: @Harry : Depending on whatever HTML and CSS he's using, the same effect could easily be achieved by playing around with `margins` and `paddings` (which has better browser support). To demonstrate this, see my answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507489/how-to-transformscale-the-top-and-bottom-part-of-a-div-using-css/35508158#35508158

Comment: @JohnSlegers: I would recommend you to have a look at this website- http://csstriggers.com/. Browser support isn't always the only consideration.

Comment: @Harry : Browser support is relevant. Performance is relevant. Existing code architecture is also relevant. That's why it's always important to have as much info about each of these criteria to determine which is the best approach in which situation. Personally, I tend to favor better browser support to minor performance benefits, but that is a rather subjective choice.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: Browser support would have been a relevant point for me too if the original question wasn't tagged with CSS3 and if OP had tried to use methods other than `transform`. Both of which they didn't and thus shows they weren't needing to support the others. Anyway, there is nothing wrong in your alternate answer. It is good as it may help somebody else in future (although I doubt if future users will need IE8 support as MS themselves has stopped its support).

Comment: @Harry : In my experience, people who ask a question on StackOverflow as simple as this one typically lack the experience to know whether `transform` or `padding + margin` is the best approach to their situation. If we want to help them the best way we can, I believe, we should help them figure this out instead of making assumptions either way. I see your point, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scaleY()` to scale just the top and bottom of an element. The generic `scale()` scales both the element in both X and Y axes.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
.scaled{
  transform: scaleY(1.1);
}

.normal:hover{
  transform: scaleY(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class='scaled'>Scaled div</div>
<div class='normal'>Normal div</div>
<div class='normal'>Normal div</div>
<div class='normal'>Normal div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't use any transforms at all.

You can achieve the same effect by playing around with your `margin`s and `padding`s, which has better browser support :

```css
.container {
    background : #789c54;
    padding : 3em 0 0 0;
}

body {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    background : #b2978c;
}

.paddy {
    padding : 2em;
}

.block1, .block2, .block3 {
    float : left;
    background : #3e402f;
    color : #d1d2c8;
    width : 33.333333%;
}

.block1 {
    background : #e4dad6;
    padding : 10px 0;
    margin : -10px 0;
    color : #77856b;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="paddy">
       Block 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div class="paddy">
       Block 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block3">
    <div class="paddy">
       Block 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ww265zes/1/))